# Adding up values to an associative array element - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, operators, associative-array

I'm having some trouble adding values to existing values in arrays.

The code:

It all comes from a big string set as the value of an hidden element in the parent page.

```
var parent = $(window.opener.document).contents();
var data = parent.find("#hdn").val();

var sp1 = data.split("=x=");
$('#timerange').text(sp1[0]); // this is where I put the first part of the string

var sp2 = sp1[1].split("|"); // the remains of it will be used to fill arr1
var arr1 = {};

  $.each(sp2, function(i, value){
    if(value != ''){
      var sp3 = value.split("<->");

      arr1[sp3[0]] += parseFloat(sp3[2]); // this is where the problem goes. i can't sum the new value with the existing value of this element, it outputs "NaN" no matter what

      $('#tableprnt tbody').append('<tr><td>'+sp3[0]+'</td><td>'+sp3[1]+'</td><td>'+sp3[2]+'</td><td>'+sp3[3]+'</td><td>'+sp3[4]+'</td><td>'+sp3[5]+'</td><td>'+sp3[6]+'</td><td>'+sp3[7]+'</td><td>'+sp3[8]+'</td><td>'+sp3[9]+'</td></tr>');
    }
  })

  console.log(arr1);
```

The point of this is to append this informations to a table so I can print it.

`data` has the string that comes from the parent page which is something like this: `2017-12-28 - 2017-12-28=x=Company name<->big string here<->123.2<->2017-12-28<->2017-12-28<->2017-12-28<->another string here<->string<->string<->string|Company name<->big string here<->123.2<->2017-12-28<->2017-12-28<->2017-12-28<->another string here<->string<->string<->string|` and it goes on.

Each element of `arr1 (sp3[0] [string])` should have the sum of it's respective value `(sp3[2] [float])`, but all i can get is `NaN` for each one of these even though I'm using `parseFloat()`.
`Console` displays `*"{element 1: NaN, element 2: NaN}"*`.
What am I missing?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: what's in `sp2` and `arr1`?

Comment: what does it prints when you  console.log(sp3[2]) shouldnt it be `sp3[1]` and what is in `sp2` and `$arr1` ?

Comment: Too many unknowns. Take a few minutes to read through [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam
console.log(sp3[2]) outputs a number.
Also, typeof sp3[2] says it's a number after I add parseFloat.

Comment: @charlietfl
I'll make sure to read it.
Sorry about that. That's the first time I ask something here.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ
sp2 is an splitted string (an array). arr1 is the main array where I'll have all the info i need.

Comment: So the main part right now is we can't reproduce from what is shown without sample input and expected results. Enough to be able to run it to reproduce your problem

Comment: By "what's in `sp2` and `arr1`? ", i meant you should provide an example of it in your question so others can reproduce.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ
Just edited it.

Comment: now whats in `data` ? add all relevant sections of the code, the `html` also via which it would be decided whats in `data`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam
I think it's clearer now.

Comment: you are using `split` to `split` the `data` string on `=x= `using this statement `data.split("=x=");` where as i cant see `=x=` anywhere in the string which means `sp1[0]` will have the whole string and there would be nothing inside the `sp1[1]` whcich will eventually result in `undefined` for the statement `sp1[1].split("|");` can you `console.log(sp1[1])` before you split it  ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam
I forgot this part. I'm really sorry about that. I just corrected it.

Comment: OK, so it looks like you donot need to use `+=` if all you are trying to do is add key value pairs to an object by parsing the string provided you should change `arr1[sp3[0]] += parseFloat(sp3[2]);` to `arr1[sp3[0]] = parseFloat(sp3[2]);`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam
Nope.
Because the index name is the Company's name and it's value adds up it's numbers.

Comment: so if i take the given string above given string there will be 3 indexes when i split the string on `|` and then each string on the index will be further split on  `<->` and the `company_name` if repeated should addup the number to the previous value for that company which will be in above case `123.2` all 3 times? is that correct ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam
Actually, the first bit from the first split (two dates) goes somewhere else in the page and the rest of if goes into this code. In the example above, it goes twice.
But, yeah. I think you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NaN` because that's what should be returned as you are trying to increment the value for the key `company_name`

```
arr1[sp3[0]] += parseFloat(sp3[2]);
```

This would fail OR say will store `NaN` on the very first iteration in the value because the actual value against the key/property "Company Name" would be `undefined` and calling `parseFloat()` on `undefined` will return you `NaN` you need to check if the object has the property defined already then increment/add the value to existing value and if it is the first time then assign the value. change the above line to the following

```
arr1[sp3[0]] = (arr1.hasOwnProperty(sp3[0])) ? (arr1[sp3[0]] + parseFloat(sp3[2])) : (parseFloat(sp3[2]));
```

Comment: You are totally right. It works great. Thank you very much for the explanation.